# Should exceptions be thrown symmetrically?

Tags: java, exception

Consider a hashtable, which would throw a NullPointerException (NPE) if key is null for both, the `get` and the `put` operations. This makes me imagine that exceptions should be symmetric, i.e NPE should be consistent for all hashtable operations involving a null node input parameter.

Is my understanding correct ?

If yes, then consider the case of an example class, Graph, which uses a HashMap underneath. It's designed to throw NPE for null input. Without the need to know its internals, it has two functions:

```
graph.addNode (node);  // throws NPE if node is null.
graph.getEdges (node); // Should empty collections be returned 
                       // or NPE for null node ?
```

According to *Effective Java*, we should prefer returning empty collections rather than null. Now if the node argument is null and we want to fetch its edges, `map.get(null node)` would return an empty collection. Is it preferred still to return NPE to maintain symmetry?

Comment: If node is not expected to be null then throw NPE as exceptions are for these cases you don't expect. Otherwise return an empty collection. And I agree with @duncan that his is opionion based as more than one approach will work here

Comment: NPE may be more consistent but empty collection may be easier to work with...

Comment: This a a very valid question to me.

Comment: @JBNizet Upon further reflection and seeing your excellent answer, I've retracted my vote. I think the answer here is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a client invokes a method that method should **fail-fast**, because detecting errors is easier than. They arise where they first occur.

In your case you have a method named `addNode(node)`. So when a client invokes it to add a node the behavior depends on that **method's contract**. I guess you do not expect that a client calls it and wants to add a `null` node. Thus you should `fail-fast` and throw a `NullPointerException` or maybe an `IllegalArgumentException`.

In the second case `node.getEdges(node)` it is also depends on the contract and the contract depends on what makes sense in your problem domain. I think that `node.getEdges(null)` should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, because a node that has no edges is different to a `null` node and I would like to distinguish between this.

**Something more to consider about the return value**

If a client gets a result from a method the result should make the **client code easier** to write and **fault-tolerant**.

In the second case `getEdges(node)` you should return an empty collection if there are no edges for a node, because this makes the client code easier. The client can avoid unnecessary `null` checks. When returning a value you should think of the client code and how it would handle the return value. Then you should choose a return value that makes the client code easier.

For example: I expect that the client code for `getEdges(node)` will look something like this

```
 Collection<Node> nodes = grap.getEdges(node);
 for(Node node: nodes){
     ...
 }
```

So if you return `null` instead of an empty collection the client code must look like this

```
 Collection<Node> nodes = grap.getEdges(node);
 if(nodes != null){
     for(Node node: nodes){
         ...
     }
 }
```

The **worst case** for the client would be if the `getEdges(node)` method throws a `NullPointerException` when there are no edges for the code. I think that it is a normal condition in a graph that no edges exist for some node. Thus I would not throw an exception.

Thats why I would return an empty collection in that case.

Comment: I agree, but the question was not what to return when a node has no edge. The question was what to return if `null` is passed to `getEdges()`. null is very different from "a node that has no edge".

Answer (score 3):

It's not a question of symmetry. It's a question of contract, and of respect of this contract. A method should define a contract regarding what it accepts as argument, what it does, and what it returns and throws. If the caller doesn't respect the contract, then it's a development bug, that should be signalled by a runtime exception.

Returning a valid result when the contract is not respected by the caller is a bad idea: it hides the bug rather than signalling it, which usually makes the problem worse and harder to find.

In your example, adding a null node to a graph makes no sense. So it should be written in the `adddNode()` javadoc that the method doesn't accept null, and the method should throw a NullPointerException.

Similarly, asking for the edges of a null node makes no sense either. A developer that would do that has probably forgotten to initialize a variable, or something like that. There is no valid reason for asking the edges of null. So it should be documented that `getEdges()` doesn't accept null, and the method should throw a NullPointerException if null is passed as argument.

When I teach this, I regularly use the following example. Suppose that you create a method named `boolean hasCancer(ExaminationResults results)`. This method must analyze the results and tell if a patient has cancer or not. Should it return true if the passed results is null? That would make the patient enter into a cancer cure, even though you don't know if he really has the cancer. Should it return false then? Well, the patient might have the cancer, and could die because the method tells that he doesn't have the cancer, without actually knowing. So the method should not return anything. It should signal the bug by throwing a NullPointerException.

Is returning an empty collection from `getEdges()` comparable to my cancer example? You don't know. Maybe the end user of your graph uses it to diagnose cancer, and maybe an empty edge collection is used to determine that the patient has a cancer. So fail fast, and throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Your example is not really applicable IMO - An empty collection is not the same as an arbitrary boolean and it's a reasonable return value, even for null.

Comment: Good answer, but I think your cancer example can be improved. A closer example would be to return a list of suggested treatments (e.g. `List<Medicine> hasCancer(ExaminationResults results)`). Then the question is - do you return an empty list on invalid input or not.

Comment: @Duncan: such an example would indeed be closer to the graph example of the OP. But the reasoning is the same.

Comment: @assylias I suppose you can do whatever you wish, provided it's well documented. But I agree with JB that a NPE would be more appropriate in cases where a `null` input makes no sense.

Comment: @assylias: take the example of Duncan: would returning an empty list of medicine be a good idea when the passed results argument is null? No it wouldn't.

Comment: @JBNizet: In some cases, it may be useful for a `TryXXX` method to return `null` for an ill-formed request, using a philosophy similar to `NaN`: if downstream code wants to do a sequence of operations whose failure is a recognized possibility, and doesn't care about why the sequence failed, percolating something *that can't be mistaken for a valid value* may be cleaner than throwing an exception.  While indication of errors via return codes is bad in cases where the errors might be ignored, a `null` return to something that would expect data is likely to be noticed.

Comment: @JBNizet: Being able to say `return GetTreatments(GetPatient(PatientId));` may be easier than `{Patient p=GetPatient(PatientId); if (p != null) return GetTreatments(p); else return null;` if the client code doesn't care about why the treatments couldn't be retrieved.  An exception might be better *if the client code isn't prepared for the possibility of failure*, but the main advantage of an exception over `null` is that it better indicates the source of a problem.  If one doesn't expect a caller to care about such things, `null` may be more efficient.